# Google play API returns error

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-api, in-app-billing, subscription, google-play

i am getting the same issue as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115381/unable-to-get-the-subscription-information-from-google-play-android-developer-ap)

. we have used almost exactly the same code. i have tried both with Client ID and Email address of the google service account in below mehotd

```
setServiceAccountId(GOOGLE_SERVICE_CLIENT_EMAIL) OR
setServiceAccountId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)
```

error changes with the change in a/c id. if i use client id, error is

> 400 Bad Request { "error" : "invalid_grant" }

and if i use service email id, error is

```
401 Unauthorized {   
"code" : 401,   "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "androidpublisher",
    "message" : "This developer account does not own the application.",
    "reason" : "developerDoesNotOwnApplication"   } ],   "message" : "This developer account does not own the application." }
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be some evidence that Google Play API does not currently work with Service Accounts (madness). There is another thread on the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824426/android-subscription-and-google-api). You can read about the Google Service Accounts [here](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/service-accounts-have-arrived.html). You can read about authentication for Android Google Play API [here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization).

Once you have done the dance on the Google API Console to get a refresh_token you can get an access token like this:

```
private String getAccessToken()
{

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
    try 
    {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type",    "refresh_token"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id",     "YOUR_CLIENT_ID);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("refresh_token", "YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN"));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine())
        {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
        return json.getString("access_token");
    }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return null;
}
```